# Send email error in java + spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, email

**i develop a web application using spring MVC, sent a email to user, when i click sent button in html form it display the following exception and here i attached my full code...**

```
public void sendMail(Employee employee) {
    String to=employee.getEmailId();//change accordingly  

      //Get the session object  

      Properties props = new Properties();  
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");  
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");  
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
      props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  
      props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
       new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
       return new PasswordAuthentication("prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com","mypassword");//change accordingly  
       }  
      });  

      //compose message  
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      try {  
       //MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
       message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com"));//change accordingly  
       message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
       message.setSubject("Email_OTP");  
       message.setText(employee.getName());  

       //send message  
    //   Transport.send(message);  
       Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
       transport.connect("prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com", Integer.valueOf(587),"prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com", "mypassword");
       transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
       transport.close();

       System.out.println("message sent successfully");  

      } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);} 

}
```

**my exception is**
    nested exception is:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com] with root cause
    java.net.UnknownHostException: prakash.ponnusamy89@gmail.com
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1900)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:638)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
        at com.prakash.employee.controller.EmployeeController.sendMail(EmployeeController.java:105)
        at com.prakash.employee.controller.EmployeeController.addEmployee(EmployeeController.java:51)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.Appl

**
```

Comment: Remove your password, put some sample text

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a MailSender like this:

```
@Bean
public org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender() {
    final JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    mailSender.setHost(HOST);
    mailSender.setUsername(USERNAME);
    mailSender.setPassword(PASSWORD);
    mailSender.setPort(PORT);
    final Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    mailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);
    return mailSender;
}
```

You can set your MailSender like this or in .xml config.

Now, you have your MailSender. You can send a mail like this:

```
@Autowired
private MailSender mailSender;

@Override
public void confirmSignUp(String email, String username, String url) {
    final SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
    msg.setFrom("noreply@aaa.com");
    msg.setTo(email);
    msg.setSubject("aaa");
    final String body = "hi";
    msg.setText(body);
    mailSender.send(msg);
}
```

It's works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
```

to this:

```
message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
```